# logback socketappender not working from webapp

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, maven, logback, appender

I use logback in my maven project and send logs using socketappender. However, the socketappender works only when i run a junit test but when I run my project from tomcat (open a web page) only console appender works.
I used lilith and the [sample server](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) in the from the logabck jar.
Here is my logback.xml which is the same as logback-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder>
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="RootSocketAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SocketAppender">
<remoteHost>127.0.0.1</remoteHost>
<port>4560</port>
<reconnectionDelay>30000</reconnectionDelay>
<includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData>
</appender>
    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RootSocketAppender" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I get this messages from tomcat console when I deploy the app:

```
10:29:45,794 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
    10:29:45,794 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/D:/programmation/workspace/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/logback-test.xml]
    10:29:45,794 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback-test.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
    10:29:45,794 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback-test.xml] occurs at [file:/D:/programmation/workspace/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/logback-test.xml]
    10:29:45,794 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback-test.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/D:/programmation/workspace/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/backoffice.jar!/logback-test.xml]
    10:29:45,856 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
    10:29:45,856 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
    10:29:45,856 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [console]
    10:29:45,872 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
    10:29:45,903 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [foo] to INFO
    10:29:45,903 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.core] to INFO
    10:29:45,903 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.beans] to INFO
    10:29:45,903 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.context] to INFO
    10:29:45,903 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.test] to TRACE
    10:29:45,903 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.web] to INFO
    10:29:45,903 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
    10:29:45,903 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [console] to Logger[ROOT]
```

thanks

Comment: The above configuration file is not well-formed.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to put < in some tags (copy paste typos). But the problem still remains.

Comment: Is there any output from the simple server?

Comment: No it is not working. It seems that logback ignores logback.xml

Comment: Have you tested it with warn or error logs (`<root level="warn">
`)? Your config works for me in Tomcat 7.0.21. You should find "|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [RootSocketAppender] to Logger[ROOT]" in your console if logback found the config file.

Comment: When I deploy the webapp, I don't get the same messages. I edited the post with my messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logback can't found the `RootSocketAppender` in your `logback-test.xml`. Make sure that it contains this appender and it's attached to the `root` logger.

Note that there is a `logback-test.xml` in the `WEB-INF/classes/` directory and an other one in the 
`WEB-INF/lib/backoffice.jar`. Maybe you should have only one in your application.

Comment: Ok, now I see, thanks :). Isn't maven responsible for handling this?

Comment: Handling what? :) If you have a `logback.xml` in your project's `src/main/resources` folder maven will put in the `war`.

Comment: Ok that's clear. But if I deploy the webapp using eclipse J2ee perspective, logback will read src/test/resources/logback-test.xml. Problem solved, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, `logback-test.xml` has a higher precedence than `logback.xml` if both found on the classpath. Maybe Eclipse adds `src/test/resources` to the classpath too. http://logback.qos.ch/manual/joran.html#auto_configuration